# Name for the function with signature: `(a -> a -> b) -> (a -> b)`

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, type-signature

I wonder whether there is a good name for functions with the following signature and implementation (Haskell-notation):

```
humble :: (a -> a -> b) -> a -> b
humble f x = f x x
```

It seems somehow related to `fold1` (`fold` with no base case).

Comment: It actually already exists as `join` (specialized to the `(->) r` monad).

Comment: It's the [`warbler`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Birds.html#v:warbler)! Or more seriously, the [`W` combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,_C,_K,_W_system).

Comment: The main difference with fold is that the second argument would be a value to apply the first to directly, rather than a list of them. (`(a -> a -> b) -> [a] -> b` rather than `(a -> a -> b) -> a -> b` as shown.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As has been mentioned by @4castle in the comments, the function you're looking for is [`join`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:join) in `Control.Monad`. It's type is

```
join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
```

The simple reader monad is `(->) r`,so if we set `m ~ (->) r`, we get

```
join :: (->) r ((->) r a) -> (->) r a
```

or, more concisely,

```
join :: (r -> r -> a) -> (r -> a)
```

which is what you want.